# for x in L: # For each item at this level TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def sumtree(L):
    tot = 0
    for x in L:  # For each item at this level
        if not isinstance(x,list):
            tot += x  # Add numbers directly
    else:
       tot += sumtree(x)  # Recur for sublists
    return tot

l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, [23, 33, [22, 22], 12, [12, 11]]]
print(sumtree(l1))
```

This shows the error:

> for x in L:  # For each item at this level
>   TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Why?

Comment: It would be helpful to show where the error occurs.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with the given code example.

Comment: @Daenyth: Please be very careful with editing the indentation of Python questions. I believe your edit removed the actual source of the bug; I've rolled it back.

Comment: your indentation sucks

Comment: @user2357112 No, your rollback causes a SyntaxError, not a TypeError. The edit was very likely correct. In fact, this SO indentation layout mistake happens a lot with Python code, thanks to the fact that the body of the code is already indented.

Comment: How do you indent things on stack when tab doesn't exist?

Comment: @Evert "Probably correct" isn't stringent enough qualification for substantive editing of code. I won't rollback because I don't want to start an edit war, but please don't assume your understanding of their indentation is correct (note that the original indentation will NOT give a `SyntaxError`, it will give an `IndentationError`)

Comment: Highlight the code and click `{}` or hit Ctrl-k.

Comment: @kpie four spaces. Tabs are a sin anyway.

Comment: @user2357112 : I'm sorry I used stack overflow for the first time... so couldn't indent properly here, but I did indent perfectly in my code, still it showed the error...

Comment: What is isInstance because based on your type error it seems that an int gets the else treatment...

Comment: @user2357112 you're right; I saw the exact error and assumed I had introduced it when I indented it the first time

Comment: @JETM the error occurs at the line "for x in L"

Comment: @kpie `isinstance` is used correctly here. `isinstance` returns True when the first argument is a child of the second argument (or a child of any of the classes in the second argument, if the second argument is iterable)

Comment: @user2357112, Adam Smith: I had (obviously) missed the indentation around the `else` part. So there was an SO formatting issue, plus an actual Python indentation issue.

Comment: @Evert as is often the case! It's easy for someone familiar with Python to correctly indent the broken SO-formatted code. It's much harder to guess how a newer coder might have indented incorrectly!! To user2357112's credit, even with the hint that it might be indentation-related, I still didn't catch the specific problem.

Answer (score 4):

Indentation is crucial in Python. You didn't correctly preserve the original indentation of your code when posting it here, but it looks like you had the `else` on the same indentation level as the `for`, rather than the `if`.

This means that instead of the `else` clause executing every time the `if` branch isn't taken, the `else` clause is executed at the end of the `for` loop if the loop doesn't end with a `break`. The loop never ends with a `break`, so the `else` clause always runs at the end of the loop, using the `x` value of the last iteration.

Correct your indentation, and the problem should be resolved:

```
def sumtree(L):
    tot = 0
    for x in L:  # For each item at this level
        if not isinstance(x,list):
            tot += x  # Add numbers directly
        else:
            tot += sumtree(x)  # Recur for sublists
    return tot
```

In the future, when posting code on Stack Overflow, copy and paste it into the question box from your original file, then highlight all the code and press Ctrl-K to indent each line an additional four spaces. This will cause it to render properly.

Comment: Ctrl-K is the win.